# Angular DOM is not updated

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I try to create effect with my slider (I use Swiper).

I can retrieve the exact position of the slider on move event, I can see that position updated in real time in console.log, but the changements are not reflected in DOM and I don't understand why ...

This is my component :

```
ngOnInit(){

    this.swiper = new Swiper(containerSelector, {
      width:375,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      initialSlide: 1
    });

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.swiper.on('setTranslate', function(translate){
      this.currentTranslate = Math.abs(translate);
      this.windowWidth = window.screen.width;
      if(this.currentTranslate == this.windowWidth){
        // Home view
        console.log("middle !");
        this.scaleYahLogo = 1;
        this.scaleYahIcn = 0;
        this.opacityChatsGrey = 1;
        this.opacityChatsColor = 0;
        this.opacityProfileGrey = 1;
        this.opacityProfileColor = 0;
        this.headerPosi = 0;
      } 
      else if(this.currentTranslate < this.windowWidth){
        // Profile view
        console.log("left !");
        this.scaleYahLogo = 0;
        this.scaleYahIcn = 1;
        this.opacityChatsGrey = 0;
        this.opacityChatsColor = 1;
        this.opacityProfileGrey = 0;
        this.opacityProfileColor = 1;
        this.headerPosi = 0;
      }
      else if(this.currentTranslate > this.windowWidth){
        // Chats view
        console.log("right !");
        this.scaleYahLogo = 0;
        this.scaleYahIcn = 1;
        this.opacityChatsGrey = 0;
        this.opacityChatsColor = 1;
        this.opacityProfileGrey = 0;
        this.opacityProfileColor = 1;
        this.headerPosi = 0;
      }
    }) 
  }
```

What did I do wrong ? I struggle since yesterday ...

Thanks all folks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` keyword in a Javascript `function()` refers to the scope of the function. To use member variables, use arrow functions. You could try the following

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.swiper.on('setTranslate', (translate) => {  // <-- arrow function instead of `function()` construct
    this.currentTranslate = Math.abs(translate);
    this.windowWidth = window.screen.width;
    if (this.currentTranslate == this.windowWidth) {
    .
    .
    .
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your modifications are made outside of angular's change detection cycle (with the `on` handler)

Use ChangeDetectorRef to notify angular of your changes

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}


this.swiper.on('setTranslate', (translate) =>{

    //Your code here
    this.currentTranslate = Math.abs(translate);
      this.windowWidth = window.screen.width;
      //...
    this.cdr.detectChanges();// Call this method
});//end translate
```

Comment: This resolved my issue as well, having custom navigation buttons outside swiper. It's frankly ridiculous having to do this, I don't understand why Ionic decided to switch to such a garbage library.

Comment: It's not Ionic, it's the way angular works, it needs to be made aware of changes made  outside of angular scope

Comment: The problem is that Ionic used to have its own slides, now they recommend using SwiperJs, even though its practices seem quite different from Ionic way.